# How to use current user object in Drupal 8?

Tags: users, 8

The answer to "[Is there a function to get the current user object that avoids accessing the global variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23000)" includes this:

> In Drupal 8, you simply use the static method \Drupal::currentUser()
>   to get the equivalent of Drupal 7 $GLOBALS['user']

I tried to use the following code:

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser(); 
$name = $user->get('name')->value;
```

But that results in an error like so:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy::get() in /home/remindme/uhoc.org/modules/testmodule/src/Form/FruitForm.php on line 173
>   (Line 173 is `$name = $user->get('name')->value;`

Do I need to used some namespace or there is some other way to access the user object?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you need to use a name space, you can include the name space directly like this

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$name = $user->get('name')->value;
```

Comment: The namespace isn't the issue.  It's the difference between the Account and the User.  IMHO, the docs on `\Drupal::currentUser` are misleading, especially when you are using an editor that doesn't autocomplete.

Comment: You may also use `$account = \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccount();` to load the full user account

Comment: @DavidThomas altho, doing that does not give you access to the user fields other than e-mail. So it doesn't really load the full user account.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks, but I just checked and could get the user fields ok from `$account` after `->getAccount()`. e.g `var_export($account->get('field_example')->value);` or `var_export($account->toArray());` was ok with field data included. You can see it calls `loadUserEntity` in the api docs

Comment: Well, doing `$account->toArray()` or `$account->get()` throws an error `Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession::get()` same for `toArray()`. I wonder if you're using a contrib module that makes this possible. I'm testing this on a fresh install of tho a bit outdated, 8.6.3

Comment: @DavidThomas Just tested on the latest 8.6.7 version, same result. Thus, if it works for you, something else must be at play. Are you using the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module perhaps?